# Merging of values in the columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

company_name = "INFY.NS"
df = yf.Ticker(company_name).history(period='400d', interval='1D')
```

Now, I have a dataframe as df1. I am doing calculations for get max and min values.

```
n = 2
df['min'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df['Close'].values, np.less_equal,order=n)[0]]['Close']
df['max'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df['Close'].values, np.greater_equal,order=n)[0]]['Close']
print()
```

Thus dataframe looks like this

[image]

But, instead of these 2 columns i.e. max and min, I want only one column named MACD and wanted to add values of max and min columns in it.
Thus,

- if max is none and min has value, add in MACD column and vice versa
- if max and min are both Nan, drop the row.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: It's recommended to add your data as text, we can not copy the contents from image.

Comment: Rather than adding a data frame, only by running the lines of code, all data is available @ThePyGuy. That's why gave the code, kindly check

Comment: And that requires one to install `yfinance`. Anyways, it's about preferences, that was just a gentle suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer to merge the columns and removing Nan columns, posting the code here.

```
df['total'] = df['min'].combine_first(df['max'])
df = df.dropna(subset=['total'])
```